# Javascript get data from txt file database

Tags: javascript, database, text

So let's say I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
[1] = {
Name = "Apple",
Description = {
    "A very tasty fruit,",
    "An apple a day keeps the doctor away."
},
Amount = 1,
Type = 0,
},

[2] = {
Name = "Banana",
Description = {
    "A very tasty yellow fruit,",
    "Bananananananananananananana Batman!"
},
Amount = 3,
Type = 0,
},

[3] = {
Name = "Cake",
Description = {
    "A very nice looking cake,",
    "It was all a lie."
},
Amount = 1,
Type = 1,
},
```

This contains data with the following format:

```
[ID] = { // int
Name = "Name", // string
Description = {"Description"}, // multiple-string
Amount = Amount, // int
Type = Type, // int
},
```

How can I make it so that if an "ID" is searched with javascript it will output all the data like so:

If ID = 1

```
Item ID: 1
Name: Apple
Description:
A very tasty fruit,
An apple a day keeps the doctor away.
Amount: 1
Type: 0
```

For C++ it's easy because I can take all the contents of the txt file and turn it into a multidimensional array, but I'm very new to javascript and have very little understanding of how it works, please help and thank you.

Comment: You will have to do some ajax. Javascript has their inbuilt on, but I normally just use jquery.

Comment: also need to convert file format to something that can be easily parsed by javascript. JSON is a simple choice ... or use back end code to read file and convert to json